# Save control's content after changing template

Tags: .net, wpf

I have two `DataTemplate` in `Window.Resources`. Handlers of buttons of `Click` event changes `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate` of the `Grid`.

```html
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>                    
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="Template1Button" Content="Template1" Click="Template1Button_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Template2Button" Grid.Column="1" Content="Template2" Click="Template2Button_Click"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource Template1}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Template1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["Template1"];
        }

        private void Template2Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["Template2"];
        }
    }
}
```

After changing template content of TextBoxes is not saved. Is it possible to save this data for example to change `ResourceDictionary` element that presents template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to save data in DataContext. Create a simple class with string properties:

```
public class Str
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }
    public string S3 { get; set; }
}
```

assign an instance to Window.DataContext

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new Str();
```

and modify template to use bindings:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=S1}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=S2}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=S1}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=S2}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=S3}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

minor change for contentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                  Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource Template1}"/>
```

Comment: Great decision! Thank you!